# Understanding QScopedPointer passing by reference

Tags: c++, qt, qsharedpointer, qscopedpointer

I've been trying to understand how to pass this as a const reference.

I have the following class:

```
class DBContext : public QObject
```

In my class MainWindow I define it as folows:

```
private:
    QScopedPointer<DBContext> dbContext;
```

How Storage class is defined:

```
class StorageData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    StorageData(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~StorageData();

    void SetDBContext(const QScopedPointer<DBContext> &db_context);

private:
    QScopedPointer<DBContext> dbContext;
```

In StorageData SetDBContext() I try to assign it with the following:

```
void StorageData::SetDBContext(const QScopedPointer<DBContext> &db_context)
{
    dbContext = db_context;
}
```

Then in the MainWindow constructor initialize it:

```
dbContext.reset(new DBContext(this));
StorageData storage;
storage.SetDBContext(dbContext);
```

Using the following in StorageData function SetDBContext():

```
_DBContext = db_context;
```

I get an error:

'QScopedPointer>::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QScopedPointer>'

**Update**

Taking the tip of using QSharedPointer and QWeakPointer.  Is this a valid approach of using these two pointers?  Also am I using clear() correctly on both Class A & B?

```
class A
private:
  QWeakPointer<DBContext> dbContext;

void A::~A()
{
     dbContext.clear()
}
void A::SetDBContext(QWeakPointer<DBContext> db_context)
{
    dbContext= db_context;
}

void A::UseCode()
{
    QSharedPointer<DBContext> ptrContext= dbContext.toStrongRef();
    ..
}

class B constructor:
private:
    QSharedPointer<DBContext> dbContext;
```

In the constructor:

```
B::B()
{
    dbContext.reset(new DBContext(this));
    QWeakPointer<DBContext> ptrDBConnect = dbContext;
    storage.SetDBContext(ptrDBConnect);
}
```

In the destructor:

```
B::~B()
{
    dbContext.clear();
}
```

Comment: what is `_DBContext`? It's not shown in your code.

Comment: My mistake in typing.  It should be dbContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on `QScopedPointer`:

> QScopedPointer intentionally has no copy constructor or assignment
>   operator, such that ownership and lifetime is clearly communicated.

The purpose of `QScopedPointer` is to keep the lifetime of the object you are pointing to tied to the scope of the `QScopedPointer`. If you could assign/copy it, then it defeats the whole point.

Comment: What Qt smartpointer is best using for passing to different class by reference only? I dont want the destructor called from the class its passed to.  I only want it called from the class that initiated it.  In this case MainWindow

Comment: One option is to use `QSharedPointer`. You can copy them, and only when all of the copies go out of scope will the object be destroyed.

Comment: It sounds like just a raw pointer to me, if you don't want to worry about lifetime control at all.

Comment: If you don’t want shared ownership but smart pointers, you could pass it as QSharedPointer but store it as QWeakPointer. Or, if you use C++11 and want to pass the ownership, use a std::unique_pointer and move semantics.

Comment: I've updated my code to use QSharePointers and QWeakPointers.  If my approach valid?